# Changing SKPhysicsBody parameters doesn't have effect

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I try to simulate behavior of different types of balls (football ball, tennis, golf, volleyball  etc). For these purposes I tried to change density, mass, size parameters of the physics body. 
In my game it doesn't have effect and I tried to simulate it in very simple app consists from ball and paddle

[image]

the ball always **rises to the same height with the same speed** regardless of mass, density, size

[image: setting for the ball]

[image]

Is this because of restitution equals 1? How can I simulate behavior of different ball types in this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to change the restitution property as well as the Lin. Dampening and Ang. Dampening per ball

for my example i have

tennis ball - rest 0.6 lin 0.2 ang 0.2

soccer ball - rest. 0.5 lin 0.3 ang 0.2

golf ball - rest 0.8 lin 0.3 ang 0.3

shot put - rest 0.1 lin 0.1 ang 0.1

[image]

here is a link to the Apple definitions of the properties

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519906-mass

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! is it possible to do this without changing restitution cause I don't need my body to lose energy after the contact, I just need bodies with different mass rise at different height.

Comment: sure, the lower the dampening values the higher the ball will bounce. even with restitution set to 1

Comment: nerd note, all of these balls would land at the same time when dropped from same height in reality, but would indeed bounce differently. Not sure if there is a way to replicate that or not.

Comment: hey nerd ;) they actually do fall at the same rate (which is what you would expect from gravity) it is probably just glitchy in the video, I bet that the giphy recorder was stuttering the scene editor. When I watch the sequence by itself without recording they all fall at the same rate

Comment: @RonMyschuk quicktime offers Screen Recording, you could always convert the video to gif after.  Give that a try and see if you get better performance out of it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks, this is good advice for anyone reading these comments. I hadn't noticed the dropping "lag" when posting this video, otherwise I probably would have recorded it from a device rather than recording right from the scene editor. I've also had considerable issues when recording from my iPad using QuickTime (it only works about half the time, and when researching it on the Apple forums it looks like it is a known issue)

Comment: @RonMyschuk, yeah unfortunately from what I have read from various people, it seems that the simulator uses software rendered open gl regardless of hardware installed, so capturing a good video at a good frame rate that doesn't interfere with the application may just be a pipe dream.